# Python Selenium, can't use execute_script() function on some websites

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

When I try to use execute_script() function on https://google.com it works, but i cant use this function on
https://rplace.live, gives an error.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)



driver.get("https://www.rplace.live")

driver.execute_script("console.log('hello')")

input("....")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AkaMehmet\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\main - Kopya.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("console.log('hello')")
  File "C:\Users\AkaMehmet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 408, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\AkaMehmet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\AkaMehmet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Function is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.168)
```

....................

Answer (score 0):

owner of https://rplace.live here.

Our site disables code evaluation as an anti-bot measure.

Hope this helps.

Please also note that while botting is not against our canvas rules, we do not support people who do so and actively restrict botting attempts that involve more than 1 IP address.